# Who is the issuer of my SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl

I have a website and SSL certificate for that domain name. It expired. I don't remember from whom I got this certificate. How do I find out?

Comment: What does it matter? It is probably someone who got a better job, got fired  or is still a co-worker of yours that couldn't care less. Either way you need a new certificate.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, double-click on the certificate to open it.  You will see the issuer of the certificate under **Issuer** on the **Details** tab.

If you have access to OpenSSL, you can who issued the certificate with:

```
openssl x509 -noout -issuer -in <certificate filename>
```

But as @RedCricket implied, you don't need to get your replacement from the same issuer as the expired one.

Comment: `you don't need to get your replacement from the same issuer as the expired one`. While technically true, it could be problematic. If other clients that access that server are in a perimeter network with constrained network access, and have firewall rules to allow access for CRL checks, a certificate from a different issuer may break their application due to they may not be able to access the CRL.